# I need help trying to create STOP sign

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a code using Python to create a STOP sign.

```
Here is my code:
wn = Screen()
sarah = Turtle()
sarah.penup()
sarah.left(180)
sarah.forward(50)
sarah.left(90)
sarah.forward(50)
sarah.left(90)
sarah.pendown()
for i in range(1,9):
    #repeat four times
    sarah.color("red")
    sarah.fillcolor("red")
    sarah.fill(True)
    sarah.forward(100)
    sarah.left(45)
    sarah.fill(False)
    sarah.penup()
    sarah.color("white")
    sarah.left(115)
    sarah.forward(125)
    sarah.right(100)
    sarah.forward(25)
    sarah.left(15)
    sarah.pendown()
    sarah.pendown()
    sarah.forward(25)
    sarah.left(15)
    sarah.right(25)
    sarah.left(80)
    sarah.left(80)
    sarah.forward(1)
    sarah.left(15)
    sarah.forward(35)
    sarah.forward(25)
    sarah.left(45)
    sarah.left(15)
    sarah.forward(15)
    sarah.forward(10)
    sarah.penup()

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: Once you paste in your code, highlight it and hit the `{}` button to format it correctly.

Comment: and you tagged it with a ton of stuff that is not at all relevant to your question

Comment: **Hey people, please be nice to this poster.**  It is a turtle question.  For all you know, it is a kid or teacher asking about one of their first bits of code.  Are you going to help the OP or are you going to callously downvote it?

Comment: We are being nice. Properly-formatted code is the first step to getting answers...

Comment: Currently, the question has two downvotes, no answers, and I had to fix the formatting just to stop the avalanche.  FWIW, there was more to it than adding the ``{}`` button.  The original cut and paste lost all the carriage returns.

Comment: I am just a kid but my teacher has us doing a project and I'm not an expert at Python. My project is to create an "STOP sign". But I have to make the turtle draw S T O P in the middle of the octagon.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on everything you're trying to do, but this might help you get started:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
sarah = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.setup(1000,1000) 

sarah.fillcolor("red")
sarah.begin_fill()
sarah.color("red") 
# Now draw an octagon
for i in range(8):  
    sarah.left(45)
    sarah.forward(50)  
sarah.end_fill() 

wn.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, here's how you won't be taught to draw a stop sign using turtle graphics:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

RADIUS = 100
FONTSIZE = int(RADIUS / 2)
FONT = ("Arial", FONTSIZE, "bold")

sarah = Turtle(visible=False)
sarah.penup()

screen = Screen()

sarah.sety(-RADIUS)
sarah.begin_poly()
sarah.circle(RADIUS, steps=8)
sarah.end_poly()
screen.register_shape("octagon", sarah.get_poly())
sarah.shape("octagon")

sarah.fillcolor("red")
sarah.home()
sarah.setheading(360 / 8 / 2)
sarah.stamp()

sarah.pencolor("white")
sarah.shapesize(0.9)
sarah.stamp()
sarah.shapesize(1.0)

sarah.sety(-FONTSIZE / 2)
sarah.write("STOP", align="center", font=FONT)

screen.exitonclick()
```

Most turtle examples emphasize *drawing* and only rarely *stamping*.  But stamping has many advantages and can solve many problems more easily than drawing:

[image]

I probably need to write a "Joy of Stamp" tutorial...